# Result of multiplying single variable functions?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

If you had two functions with single variables (i.e. f(x) and g(y)), would multiplying them yield a function of two variables?

Like, would f(x)g(y) = h(x,y) ?

Comment: If the variables are different? Yes. You can see this in joint probability densities.

Comment: $f(x)\cdot g(y)$ is a special form of a function $h(x,y)$ for which the double integral or the partial derivates are parituclar easy to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even if you just had one function $f(x)$, then $h(x,y)\stackrel{def}{=}f(x)f(y)$ is a function of two variables.

To be careful, you should specify the domain and range. In your original example, if $f:A\to\mathbb R$ and $g:B\to\mathbb R$, and you define $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$, then $h:A\times B\to\mathbb R$ where $A\times B$ is the Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, i.e., the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement to be a function is that there aren't several values associated to given value of the argument (here a given pair $(x,y)$).

As $f$ and $g$ are themselves functions, this is granted.